# Postgres delete all duplicate records but one by sorting

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to know, in Postgres, how to delete all duplicate records but one by sorting by a column.

Let's say I have the following table `foo`:

```
 id                 | name |  region   |          created_at
--------------------+------+-----------+-------------------------------
                  1 | foo  | sydney    | 2018-05-24 15:40:32.593745+10
                  2 | foo  | melbourne | 2018-05-24 17:28:59.452225+10
                  3 | foo  | sydney    | 2018-05-29 22:17:02.927263+10
                  4 | foo  | sydney    | 2018-06-13 16:44:32.703174+10
                  5 | foo  | sydney    | 2018-06-13 16:45:01.324273+10
                  6 | foo  | sydney    | 2018-06-13 17:04:49.487767+10
                  7 | foo  | sydney    | 2018-06-13 17:05:13.592844+10
```

I would like to delete all duplicates by checking for (name, region) tuple, but keep the one with the greatest `created_at` column. The result would be:

```
 id                 | name |  region   |          created_at
--------------------+------+-----------+-------------------------------
                  2 | foo  | melbourne | 2018-05-24 17:28:59.452225+10
                  7 | foo  | sydney    | 2018-06-13 17:05:13.592844+10
```

But I do not know where to begin. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery with `ROW_NUMBER` and `PARTITION BY` to filter out rows that have duplicate regions while retaining the most recent in each region. Ensure your subquery uses the `AS` keyword to prevent Postgre syntax errors:

```
SELECT * 
FROM foo 
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT a.id 
  FROM (
    SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY region 
        ORDER BY created_at DESC
    ) row_no 
    FROM foo
  ) AS a 
  WHERE row_no > 1
);
```

... returns the rows to be deleted. Replace `SELECT *` with `DELETE` when you're satisfied with the result to delete the rows.

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/75b58/4)

Comment: Why are we using `PARTITION BY region` rather than `PARTITION BY region, name`? What is the difference?

Comment: Your example indicates your dataset has the same value for `name` across the board - adding it to the `PARTITION BY` would be immaterial to the output for the example.

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM foo
      WHERE id IN
               (SELECT id
                  FROM (SELECT id,
                               ROW_NUMBER ()
                               OVER (PARTITION BY region
                                     ORDER BY created_at DESC)
                                  row_no
                          FROM foo)
                 WHERE row_no > 1)
```